# Click en el elemento hijo

Tags: angularjs

Hice una directiva que lo inserto en el **div** padre para restringir algunas cosas (tales restricciones que realizo no pongo en el ejemplo), pero también quiero escuchar cuando se hace **click** en el **segundo elemento** solo en el segundo elemento, como puedo escuchar cuando se hace **click**?

***Nota: solo quiero insertar en el div padre la directiva***

```js
angular
  .module('MyApp', [])
  .directive(
    'clickMe',
    function() {
      return {
        link: function(scope, element) {
          element.on('click', function() {
            console.log('click');
          });
        },
      };
    }
  );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="MyApp">
  <div click-me>
    clickeame
    <div id="one">
      click 2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Es tan fácil como comprobar quién está recibiendo el evento:

```js
angular
  .module('MyApp', [])
  .directive(
    'clickMe',
    function() {
      return {
        link: function(scope, element) {
          
          element.on('click', function(evento) {
            if (evento.target.id=='one') {
              console.log('Click on click 2');
            } else {
              console.log('click');
            }
          });
        },
      };
    }
  );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="MyApp">
  <div click-me>
    clickeame
    <div id="one">
      click 2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hola puedes explicar un poco que hace `<div click-me>` ? Gracias!

Comment: Si te fijas ya estaba en el código original, no está relacionado con la pregunta, pero te explico: es lo que busca AngularJS para aplicar su directiva. click-me es transformado a "camelcase" (clickMe) e identifica al elemento objetivo de la directiva declarada

Comment: Muchas gracias, desconocía este comportamiento. Buscaré más información para dominarlo. Es angular o angularJS?

Comment: En este caso es AngularJS

Answer (score 1):

He encontrado la manera de hacer lo que quieres, pero solo funciona con `jQuery`.

Si te fijas he añadido la id `#one` del div

```
element.on('click', '#one', function ()
```

```js
angular
  .module('MyApp', [])
  .directive(
    'clickMe',
    function() {
      return {
        link: function(scope, element) {
           element.on('click', '#one', function () {
            console.log('click');
          });
        },
      };
    }
  );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="MyApp">
  <div click-me>
    clickeame
    <div id="one">
      click 2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```